# How can I show an ellipsis in a DataGrid if the content of a cell is greater than its width?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Is it possible to show `...` if the content of some cell in a `DataGrid` is greater than the specified `ColumnWidth`?
Something like:

```
-------------------------------
|   Name   |    Last Name     |
-------------------------------
| LongNa.. |                  |
-------------------------------
```

Comment: would this be of any use to you? [Show Ellipsis In Grid Example](http://mytechissues.blogspot.ca/2008/08/show-ellipsis-text-in-gridview.html) I have used this to effect before.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`TextTrimming` is what you are looking for. Use the `DataGridTemplateColumn` and insert a `TextBlock` into the `CellTemplate` which supports `TextTrimming`. Sample -

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSourceForYourGrid}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="20">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Try this code, I think it'll work:

```
public static string StringEllipsis(DataGrid grid, string text, float columnWidth)
{
    // you can customize this variables, for your preferences
    string yourEllipsis = "..."; 
    string yourFontFamily = "Arial";
    float yourFontSize = 9F;
    float yourTolerance = 1F;

    Graphics graphics = grid.CreateGraphics();
    if (graphics.MeasureString(text, new Font(yourFontFamily, yourFontSize)).Width <= (columnWidth + yourTolerance))
        return text;

    while (graphics.MeasureString(text + yourEllipsis, new Font(yourFontFamily, yourFontSize)).Width > (columnWidth + yourTolerance))
        text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 1);

    return text + yourEllipsis;
}
```